# How to make ANOVAs with a 2*2*3*3 mixt design with 2 between-subjets variables and 2 within-subjects variables?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I get in trouble with my statisics.

My design is as following :

*2 between subject VI (independant variable)* : 
Variable A (A1, A2) and Variable B (B1, B2)

*2 Within-subject VI :* 
repeated Variable C (C1, C2, C3) and D (D1, D2, D3).

On my Excel, I get two columns that precise the modality of each of the 2 inter factors (A1, A2 ; B1, B2). I also get 9 columns with my quantitative VD (dependant variable) corresponding to the 9 possible combinations of both my repeated factors (see picture):

[image]

I want to study main and interactional effects of my 4 VI on my VD.

I started statistical analysis on STATISTICA. I've seen it is possible to make a standard linear model with several within-subject variables: it asks me to labbel each one of the intra-factors and give the level, meaning the number of modality per intra factor). However, STATISTICA runs what it calls a "regular factorial plan", that does not satisfy me, since it doesn't ask anywhere which columns match with which modality of VI B (B1, B2 or B3) and which modality of VI D (D1, D2, D3).

Do you have any idea of how I could run ANOVAs including 2 between subject variables and 2 within subject variables in which repeated factors are well defined ? 
I'll be able to use STATISTICA or R if needed.

Do not hesitate to ask for precisions. 
Thank you very much

Del =)